# this code previously worked properly i received message but now it is not working it only shows success message but i did not received the message

Tags: node.js, amazon-sns

async sendMessage(testId: number) {

```
require('dotenv').config();
const test = await this.testRepository.findOne({
  where: { id: testId },
  relations: ['tester', 'customer', 'device.address'],
});
if (!test) {
  throw new BadRequestException('test id not found');
}
const deviceData = await this.deviceRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    id: test.device.id,
    isDelete: false,
  },
  relations: ['customer'],
});
const data = await this.addressRepository.findOne({
  where: { device: deviceData },
});
var mobileNo = test.customer.phoneNo;

var params = {
  Message: `A backflow test was completed successfully at ${data.addressLine1} on ${test.dateOfTest} by ${test.tester.technicianName}.`,
  PhoneNumber: mobileNo,
};
return new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010–03–31' })
  .publish(params)
  .promise()
  .then((message) => {
    console.log('Message SEND SUCCESS');
  })
  .catch((err) => {`your text`
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  });
```

}

i want to know how to fix it and the cause for the problem it is now showing me success message but i did not recive the messagge

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.